How to create a table of contents in sandcastle word format？
I'm documenting a C# program in Sandcastle. Documents must be created in Word(OpenXML) format. I would like to prepare a table of contents, but the default settings do not create a table of contents, so I looked for a setting item, but I couldn't find a setting to toggle whether to output a table of contents in Word format.
Is there no choice but to create each item manually?
I looked for a setting item, but I couldn't find a setting to toggle whether to output a table of contents in Word format.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
